# How can I build 'bazel' for image retraining on TensorFlow Inception-V3

Tags: python, bazel

I'm trying image retraining on TensorFlow Inception-V3 by referring official website.
https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/image_retraining/

### When I try build the retrainer,

### $ bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain

### I got this error:

ERROR: /home/ubuntu/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl:509:18: function 'repository_rule' does not exist.

### ERROR: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package 'external': Extension 'third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl' has errors.

Does anyone know how can I fix it?

Comment: What is your bazel version? Did you run ./configure?

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/6d6c3f23ea057775b72c52817759b25c). Follow all the instructions and see if that solves the problem.